# how to wait for the python logging module thread? Or how to merge the thread to main thread?

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to write a interactive module, which will have the following codes:

```
logging.info("message 1 xxxxx")
logging.info("message 2 xxxxx")
input("enter y or n >>")
```

Then it turns out the the message 1 and message 2 will not always printed before the "enter y or n". Every time it shows a different order. It seems the logging module will start a new thread.

But I want these messages be printed in order, so is there any sort of wait method? or can I merge the thread into the main thread? I searched the documentation with "wait" and "thread" but cannot find too much.